# Is "punchline" usual in modern English?

Tags: word-usage

I came across the word "punchline", so I looked up its meaning in the dictionary http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/punchline. Nevertheless, there seems no such word in current usage. Thus, I began to wonder whether it is usual in modern English? Then, I came across this word again in this dictionary http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=punchline, and I am wondering whether the explanation is correct?

Comment: Yes, the definition in the urban dictionary is correct and yes it is in current and widespread use today.  What makes you say it's not in current usage? It's usage is, in fact, increasing: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=punchline%2Ctoadstool&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpunchline%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctoadstool%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Jim: Thank you so much, and what makes me say it's not in current usage is I being a non-native English speaker :)

Comment: Search by "punch line" and you will find lots of references, for ex. [punch line](http://onelook.com/?w=punch+line&ls=a) in OneLook Dictionary Search.

Comment: Thanks so much. Apparently I have not digged deeply enough.

Comment: You can check a freely available corpus such as [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/).  You'll find that it's in use, both with and without a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in wide usage, although sometimes it's spelled as "punch line", but "punchline" is very common too. Some recent headlines:

- [WNET's New Advertising Campaign Uses Reality TV as a Punchline](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/05/27/business/media/wnets-new-advertising-campaign-uses-reality-tv-as-a-punchline.html?_r=0) (New York Times)
- [The punchline is Obama's dignity](http://www.bostonglobe.com/opinion/2014/03/16/the-punchline-obama-dignity/Z6oESKIuje2kmjHg6E1HuK/story.html) (Boston Globe)
- [Où est le punchline? The art of standup in a second language](http://www.theguardian.com/stage/2014/aug/05/edinburgh-2014-standup-in-a-second-language-eddie-izzard)

In all three cases the definition means "the point of a joke or story; the part that makes it funny or otherwise provides an essential element":

- Reality TV is the source of the humor in the advertising campaign.
- The opinion writer believes Obama's dignity suffered by trivializing it as a joke.
- It may be tough for foreign audiences to find the punchline in cross-language jokes.